# The parent child relationship of Linux filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, directory

Where is The parent child relationship recorded? That is to say, for example, how does Linux know under the folder /lib there is a /lib/src file or folder? Is it in /lib's inode?

And a related question: suppose under /folderA there is one file, and under /folderB there are  one million files, is there any difference between the size of the two folder themselves, excluding the file under them?

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where is The parent child relationship recorded?

In Directory of the parent.

Directory `/lib` contains directory entries, consisting of `i-node` and `name` of files and directories, present in `/lib`.

The `i-node` contains all the information about the file: the file type, the file's access permission bits, the size of the file etc.

> suppose under /folderA there is one file, and under /folderB there are
>   one million files, is there any difference between the size of the two
>   folder themselves, excluding the file under them?

Assuming the directory entry is of 16 bytes, folderA size would be 16 bytes, and folderB size would be 1,000,000*16 bytes, regardless of the size of the files.